# how to implement "select/unselect all" checkbox in php?

Tags: php, html

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
<title>View Users</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}
div.greetblock, div.serverresponse {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align: center;
}
tr > td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;
  
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FA9A8B;
  color: #fff;
}
tr#header{
background: #F78371;
}

div#norecord{
margin-top:10px;
width: 15%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
input,select{
cursor: pointer;
}
img{
margin-top: 10px;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
}
select{
width: 200px
}
div.leftdiv{
width: 100%;
padding: 0 10px;
float: center;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 5px;
height: 320px;
text-align:center;
}
div.rightdiv{
width: 45%;
padding: 0 10px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 5px;
height: 320px;
text-align:center;
}
hidediv{
display: none;
}
p.header{
height: 40px;
background-color: #EB5038;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
text-align:center;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
textarea{
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: normal;
}

</style>
<script>

function sendMsg(){
var msgLength = $.trim($("textarea").val()).length;
var checkedCB = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
if( checkedCB == 0){
 alert("You must select atleast one User to send message");
}else if(msgLength == 0){
 alert("You left the message field blank, please fill it");
}else{
 var formData = $(".wrapper").find("input").serialize() + "&imgurl="+ $("#festival").val() + "&message=" + $("textarea").val(); 
 $.ajax({type: "POST",data: formData, url: "processmessage.php", success:function(res){
  $(".greetblock").slideUp(1000);
  $(".serverresponse").prepend(res).hide().fadeIn(2000);
 }});
}
}
$(function(){
 $(".serverresponse").hide()
 $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
   $(this).parent().css("border","3px solid red");
  }else{
   $(this).parent().css("border","0px");
  }
 });
 
 $("div.leftdiv, div.rightdiv").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("background","#FAFAFA");
 },function(){
  $(this).css("background","#fff");
 });
 
 $("#festival").change(function(){
  $("img").attr("src",$(this).val());
 });
 
 $("#sendmsg").click(function(){
  $(".serverresponse").fadeOut(300,function(){
   $(".greetblock").fadeIn(1000);
  });  
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0; 
?>
<?php
    if ($no_of_users > 0) {
?>

<div class="greetblock">
<div class="leftdiv">
<p class="header">Select Users to whom you want to send an announcement
</p>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr id="header"><td>Id</td><td>EmailId</td><td>Send Message?</td></tr>
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
?> 
<tr>
<td><span><?php echo $row["id"] ?></span></td>
<td><span><?php echo $row["emailid"] ?></span></td>
<td><span class="wrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="sendmsg[]" value="<?php echo $row["emailid"] ?>"/></span></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</div>

<div class="leftdiv">
<p class="header">Type your message
</p>
<textarea cols="15" rows="5" value="txtarea">

</textarea>

<center>
<button onclick="sendMsg()">Send Message</button>
</center>


</div>

</div>
<div class="serverresponse hidediv">
<center><button id="sendmsg">Send Message Again</button></center>
</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div id="norecord">
No records in MySQL DB
</div>
<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code shows a list of users to whom i can send a message using google cloud messaging.
Each user is shown in a table with a checkbox for each.
I can select the users out the the table to send them a message
I want to add a select/unselect check box to this. 
can someone help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PHP to select/unselect multiple HTML checkboxes? Sounds like JavaScript would be a better solution.

Comment: See the [link](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-checkall.php)

Answer (score 0):

As @Mex and @Lai note, most people use Javascript for this. You can use a pure Javascript approach as in @Lai's link or jQuery if you happen to be using that.

If, for some reason, you need to use PHP for this, you would probably want to have a "Select All" checkbox. Traditionally, this is in the table header above the individual row checkboxes.

When someone submits the form, you can check the "Select All" checkbox and, if it is checked, handle the form as if the user had checked all of the checkboxes individually.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am new to coding. I want to add a select all checkbox like you suggested. can you help me with the code ??

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's work

```
<html>
<head><title>View Users</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}
div.greetblock, div.serverresponse {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align: center;
}
tr > td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;

}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FA9A8B;
  color: #fff;
}
tr#header{
background: #F78371;
}

div#norecord{
margin-top:10px;
width: 15%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
input,select{
cursor: pointer;
}
img{
margin-top: 10px;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
}
select{
width: 200px
}
div.leftdiv{
width: 45%;
padding: 0 10px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 5px;
height: 320px;
text-align:center;
}
div.rightdiv{
width: 45%;
padding: 0 10px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 5px;
height: 320px;
text-align:center;
}
hidediv{
display: none;
}
p.header{
height: 40px;
background-color: #EB5038;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
text-align:center;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
textarea{
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
<script>

function sendMsg(){
var msgLength = $.trim($("textarea").val()).length;
var checkedCB = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
if( checkedCB == 0){
    alert("You must select atleast one User to send message");
}else if(msgLength == 0){
    alert("You left the message field blank, please fill it");
}else{
    var formData = $(".wrapper").find("input").serialize() + "&imgurl="+ $("#festival").val() + "&message=" + $("textarea").val();  
    $.ajax({type: "POST",data: formData, url: "processmessage.php", success:function(res){
        $(".greetblock").slideUp(1000);
        $(".serverresponse").prepend(res).hide().fadeIn(2000);
    }});
}
}

$(function(){
    $(".serverresponse").hide()
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){

        }else{

            $(this).parent().css("border","0px");
        }
    });

$("#select_all").click(function(){
      var checked_status = this.checked;
      $("input[name='sendmsg[]']").each(function(){
        this.checked = checked_status;
      });
    });


    $("div.leftdiv, div.rightdiv").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background","#FAFAFA");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("background","#fff");
    });

    $("#festival").change(function(){
        $("img").attr("src",$(this).val());
    });

    $("#sendmsg").click(function(){
        $(".serverresponse").fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(".greetblock").fadeIn(1000);
        });     
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0;   
?>
<?php
    if ($no_of_users > 0) {
?>

<div class="greetblock">
<div class="leftdiv">
<p class="header">Select Users to send message
</p>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/>Select All</td>
<table>
<tr id="header"><td>Id</td><td>EmailId</td><td>Send Message?</td></tr>
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
?> 
<tr>

<td><span><?php echo $row["id"] ?></span></td>
<td><span><?php echo $row["phones"] ?></span></td>
<td><span class="wrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="sendmsg[]" id="chk" value="<?php echo $row["phones"] ?>"/></span></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
</div>
<div class="rightdiv">
<p class="header">Type your message
</p>
<textarea cols="15" rows="5" value="txtarea">
</textarea>
<br/>

<center>
<button onclick="sendMsg()">Send Message</button>
</center>
</div>

</div>
<div class="serverresponse hidediv">
<center><button id="sendmsg">Send Message Again</button></center>
</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div id="norecord">
No records in MySQL DB
</div>
<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```